# Difference between query and distribution in causal inference

Tags: mathematical-statistics, causality, treatment-effect, epidemiology, causal-diagram

Reading the causality literature, we see the concepts of "interventional" and "counterfactual" query as well as "interventional" and "counterfactual" distribution mentioned frequently without any explanation of how these concepts are related and/or different.

For example, see these resources:

1. https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-020-0197-y
2. https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.00035

Could someone please explain the technical/mathematical/statistical difference between:

1. Counterfactual query and counterfactual distribution
2. Interventional query and interventional distribution

Ideally, please provide one example for each concept to better understand their differences?

Comment: Any type of distribution in causality is still just a regular probability distribution (just arising in some specific causal context), if that helps.